# Can the rendering of the JavaFX 2/8 font be improved?

Tags: fonts, javafx-2, antialiasing

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and coding an application to display some labels ( using the Label class ). I also tried to use Text class and set the smoothing type to LCD. The result is the same, the font looks blurry, its margins are scattered, and you have to set its size to a pretty big number in order to be readable ( note I have some text paragraph displayed ).

I know JavaFX2 has LCD sub-pixel rendering but still, can something be done so that the font doesn't look so ugly? ( maybe I'm missing something for 2.X or don't know of existence of something in 8.X )

Is there any way to check if LCD sub-pixel rendering is active or not?

Regards,

Comment: See [a dev mailing list thread on JavaFX font rendering](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-August/009822.html).

Comment: As the Oracle guy says:"On Linux we are providing a freetype backend but likely it won't be enable by defaults (which means we will be using T2K there). I don't think I'll have the time to fix Linux this time around." here https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-14187, I'd like to point out 3 things:1. look at eclipse's font on Linux and then how the JavaFX font looks. 2. ARE WE SUPPOSED TO BE CROSS PLATFORM?!?! 3. Android may have holograms until you get this toolkit right.

Comment: It seems this problem is not an issue on the Windows platform as sadly, it appears that resolving issues affecting Windows are given precedence to those affecting the (much better) Linux platforms.

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
System.setProperty("prism.lcdtext", "false");
System.setProperty("prism.text", "t2k");
```

both or one at time.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the font of the entire application to `'Ubuntu Light'`, gives me a perfect appearance. I have tried some other fonts as well, but they worsened the appearance.

**Step 1:** Add the following style in *application.css* file.

```
.text {
    -fx-font-family: "Ubuntu Light";
}
```

**Step 2:** Apply the style to your parent scene.

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
```